# IP camera using a USB 3G Modem using same IP address on every boot

Tags: raspbian

I am looking to build a video monitoring system using raspberry pi. I used the motion software, and it worked well with ethernet.

Now, I am want to get it working with a 3G USB dongle. I am using a ZTE MF70 3G modem.

The problem is that with a 3G dongle, the IP address keeps on changing. How can I overcome this problem ? Is there a software or something to do so. I want the camera to always use the same IP address and port.

I want to view the live stream from anywhere in the world.

Or is there anything other than motion that I can use ??

Please help.

Comment: you'd better ask about handling dynamic DNS on superuser.stackexchange

Comment: You cannot control the IP address given by the internet provider to your modem. You have to deal with a changing IP address. Ways to overcome this is using some dynamic DNS service or building a VPN where the internet IP address is controlled by you.

Answer (score 1):

Some cell providers offer static IP address services, but they charge you through the nose for them.  Sometimes to the tune of $500 setup fee, plus $10 (or more) a month.  This may or may not require specific hardware like a cradle-point modem/router/WAP.  I don't know if the Raspberry Pi would be 'supported', not saying it won't work, but they may not help you set it up, which can be challenging.

The other option is, like @lenik said, a dynamic DNS service.  You should be able to easily find a free one somewhere.